# Liferay: Change URL Format for document links inside of web content (journal article)

Tags: content-management-system, liferay, document

Is it possible to change the URL Format for document links inside of web content (journal article). It will be userfull for me to see the kind of mime-type of this document inside the url. May be it is simple to add to `a`-element some css class, like `<a class="pdf" href="...`

At last the request is to show different icons before such links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `journal.transformer.regex` see docu for `portal.properties`:

```
journal.transformer.regex.pattern.0=<a href="/documents/(.*\.)(pdf|doc)("|(/.*"))>
journal.transformer.regex.replacement.0=<a class="$2" href="/documents/$1$2$3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the link tag available in ckEditor to included document Links? If yes, then the dialog which pops up when you add links has a third tab called Advanced, where you can specify stylesheet classes.

Comment: Yes, that would be not comfortable workaround. I would prefer to automate this.

Comment: I dont think there is other option. You may have to modify ckeditor's files to change the view and behaviour.